# Testing promise without having to mock a resolution?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I've hit a wall on a small problem. I would like to make a general unit test for a function that returns a promise, without having to mock out how the internals of the function come to the resolution of the promise.

Ex:

```
function doGet(opts) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ajaxOptions = extend({}, {
        type: 'GET',
        headers: sampleHeaders,
        success: (data) => {
            resolve(data);
        },
        error: (xhr) => {
            reject(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }, opts);

    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
 });
}
```

I have a passing test suite, with the mock of $.ajax yielding to success, but since the above code could be refactored in the future I would like to remain general in the test and be sure that this function at all times returns a promise regardless of internal implementation.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your test(s)? This would explain what exactly you're trying to test and how. It would also be helpful if you share your thoughts about what kind of changes in the `doGet()` implementation you anticipate.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I came to the conclusion that this function, regardless of resolved or rejected, needs to return a promise. 

I would up going with a simple test that, simple checks that the function returns a promise. 

To answer your question regarding future refactoring. Since this is an older implementation of `js` with the inevitable update to a more modern `js`, we may be able to leverage something like `fetch` and remove the dependency on `jquery`. So not tying the test to specific implementation was important.